# c# code to fire a key generation when condition is true

Tags: c#

Hy, I would like to know - How can i fire the key press of,say, "F6" when my condition is true. I am working on c#. What header files should i include? What  is the scripplet of the c#code which press F6 button when the condition is true. 
Thank you

Comment: you can use acii value of F6 button to fire it

Comment: @TusharGupta: I doubt it. What would be the "ascii value" of the F6 button?

Answer (score 3):

[SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send.aspx) can be used to send a keystroke to the active application:

```
SendKeys.Send("{F6}");
```

Note, though, that this should only be used as a last resort, if there is no other way to remotely control another application. Direct interfaces (e.g. COM automation) are usually more reliable and robust.

Comment: Since you're sending it to the *active* application in response to user input, that is probably *your own*, in which case it's not only fragile but rather pointless. Just invoke the desired method directly.

Comment: Heinzi,    I have tried that. I couldn't get that. Like. When i type SendKeys.Send itself it shows me an error. Should any namespace be included? What changes should be made in COM  properties?

Comment: @user2522592: Click on the documentation link at the beginning of my answer. There it says that the namespace is `System.Windows.Forms` and that the required reference is `System.Windows.Forms.dll`.